# Rails Model Validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I have a model and adding some validations

This is what I originally had:

```
  validates :speed,
    allow_blank: true,
    numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
```

But I keep getting errors when importing items from my CSV file stating that

> Speed must be an integer

I then changed it to:

```
  validates :speed,
    numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }, unless: "speed.nil?"
```

But I get the same errors here too.

Basically I want it to validate that speed is numeric and greater than 1 unless no speed is passed in and to allow that blank value.

Any ideas?

CSV Importer:

```
def self.import_from_csv(file)
    Coaster.destroy_all

    csv_file = CSV.parse(
      File.read(
        file.tempfile,
        {encoding: 'UTF-8'}
      ),
      headers: true,
      header_converters: :symbol
    )

    csv_file.each do |row|

      coaster_name = row[:name]

      # No need to keep track of coasters already in the database as the CSV only lists each coaster once unlike parks

      # create the new coaster
      park = Park.find_by_name_and_location_1(row[:park], row[:location_1])
      manufacturer = Manufacturer.find_by_name(row[:manufacturer])

      coaster = Coaster.create!({
        name:             row[:name],
        height:           row[:height],
        speed:            row[:speed],
        length:           row[:length],
        inversions:       row[:inversions] == nil ? 0 : row[:inversions],
        material:         (row[:material].downcase if row[:material]),
        lat:              row[:coaster_lat],
        lng:              row[:coaster_lng],
        park_id:          park.id,
        notes:            row[:notes],
        powered:          row[:powered],
        manufacturer_id:  (manufacturer.id if manufacturer),
        covering:         row[:covering],
        ride_style:       row[:ride_style],
        model:            row[:model],
        layout:           row[:layout],
        dates_ridden:     row[:dates_ridden],
        times_ridden:     row[:times_ridden],
        order:            row[:order],
        on_ride_photo:    row[:on_ride_photo] == 1 ? true : false,
        powered:          row[:powered] == 1 ? true : false
      })

      ap "Created #{row[:name]} at #{row[:park]}"

    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the value for speed from csv is interpreted as string. You may use .to_i with that specific value that you are using for speed. Change your code like this:

```
  park = Park.find_by_name_and_location_1(row[:park], row[:location_1])
  manufacturer = Manufacturer.find_by_name(row[:manufacturer])
  row_speed = row[:speed].blank? ? nil : row[:speed].to_i

  coaster = Coaster.create!({
    ..... 
    speed:            row_speed,
    .....
  })
```

And then in validation:

```
validates :speed, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }, allow_nil: true
```

Comment: can you paste your code that u are using for importing csv to database.

Comment: Added in Original post. I checked the CSV and the items in there are not quotes so I can't see why it would think they are strings?

Comment: Which validation would I use with that, the first example I posted or the second? I want to validate the numericality line if a value is present otherwise just allow blank.

Comment: validates :speed, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }, allow_nil: true, allow_blank: true

Comment: Perfect. Had to tweak the ternary slightly but thanks! Rolled it out to height and length too.

Answer (score 0):

Validations accept an `:allow_nil` argument, as noted here in the Rails guides: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-nil

If the attribute is nil when `:allow_nil` is true, that particular validation will only run if the attribute in question is present.

Answer (score 0):

I think, validates numericality accepts `allow_nil` attribute. Try this:

```
validates :speed, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }, allow_nil: true
```